# What is LongAdder related to cassandra+spark connector?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, databricks

When i load data into cassandra with using databricks, its getting the issue with
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder

Its simple saveToCassandra to table.

I looked this twitter jsr166e jar in maven , its very old, added in 2013, 
I don't know why this jar is not available in Spark+cassandra_coonector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error indicates you are missing dependencies and / or the Spark Cassandra connector is not on the runtime classpath of the Spark application. Not sure how you installed the connector but you should have used the packages method to ensure that dependencies are met and the Connector is correctly configured.

Read more [HERE](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md)

Hope that helps,
Pat

Comment: Additional Link on FAQ: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#why-cant-the-spark-job-find-spark-cassandra-connector-classes-classnotfound-exceptions-for-scc-classes